# Bash script with scrot area not working

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I created a bash script to use for interactive screen capture and another one for window capture. I'm linking to these with keyboard shortcuts in Linux. The window capture script works without problems:

```
#!/bin/sh  
scrot -u 'ScreenShot_%Y-%m-%d_at_%I:%M:%S-%p.png' -e 'mv $f ~/Pictures/scrot-screenshots'
```

But the script for for area capture (user selects area with mouse drag) does not work, even though the command works in terminal:

```
#!/bin/sh  
scrot -s 'ScreenShot_%Y-%m-%d_at_%I:%M:%S-%p.png' -e 'mv $f ~/Pictures/scrot-screenshots'
```

What am I doing wrong? Or maybe a better question is what is preventing the script from letting me select an area of the screen?

Comment: does executing the script produce any errors? Which ones?

Comment: you added the `bash` tag, but you use `sh`. Try with `#!/bin/bash` maybe?

Comment: There are no errors that i can see in bash_history. Going to try your last suggestion on the non-working script.

Comment: #!/bin/bash same issue.

Comment: your errors don't appear in bash_history; does the script print some errors on the command line when you execute it? What does it do, and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: if i run the script form the terminal ./scrot_screenshot_area it works. If I try to tie it to a keyboard shortcut, it does not. I have a keyboard shortcut tied to that one script (ALT 3). if i change the -s to -u, the keyboard shortcut works. If i change the -u back to -s, nothing happens. But the -s command works in terminal...just not with keyboard shortcut.

Comment: try getting the output of your script in a certain file. for example: `scrot .... > /tmp/error 2>&1` . Then after pressing your shortcut your can analyse that file... probably this error output is already somewhere present on your system, but that depends on your os etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I manged to get it working by adding a delay to give the giblib resource time (2/10 of a second) to load:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 0.2 ; scrot -s 'ScreenShot_%Y-%m-%d_at_%I:%M:%S-%p.png' -e 'mv $f ~/Pictures/scrot-screenshots'
```

**How I found the solution:**
I couldn't figure out how to get errors to output to a file because running my script from terminal didn't produce any errors. Double clicking the script ran properly and `script > file 2>&1` in terminal didn't give me any errors because it ran properly from terminal. I only had errors when I tried to use the keyboard shortcuts (keybindings) attached to the second command from my original post. To see the error that finally lead to the above solution, I downloaded:

```
`apt-get install xbindkeys` && `apt-get install gconf-editor`
```

I ran gconf-editor and used the Run Action to executed the script the same manner it would be executed if I was using the keybindings...but attached to a terminal output. That gave me the error output I needed to see:

```
giblib error: couldn't grab pointer:Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Which lead me to this post:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=86507 for the tip.

Comment: This was also the solution when binding to a key in XMonad

Answer (score 3):

For whomever the jtlindsey's answer did not work for solving the problem :

```
giblib error: couldn't grab pointer:Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Another solution could be this : just before calling scrot, run the command :

```
xdotool key XF86Ungrab
```

This should release the pointer, and the scrot command should work after it.
Note : the [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40458/command-for-forcing-a-pointer-ungrab-captured-mouse-release)) claims that before executing previous xdotool command, it would possibly be required to execute :

```
setxkbmap -option grab:break_actions
```